# Searching for unknown characters in an Oracle database

Tags: regex, oracle

Is there a way to search an Oracle database (some sort of regex I suspect) to find unknown characters (which often appear as □ □)?

Comment: If your system only supports standard ASCII characters, then you could search your database for looking for characters whose code is less than 32 or greater than 255 for example. You can find the ASCII character codes in this [link](http://www.asciitable.com/). EDIT: You can also apply the same principle if you are working with another character set, like UNICODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way to search over entire Oracle database. You would need a tedious script that walks over various types of Oracle objects in dba_objects, and then descends into each (for a trivial example if an object is a table you need to parse the columns, and if a column contains a character data, REGEXP_LIKE; but there are more types of objects, for example a package - do you want to search package's literals too?). I would instead make manually an explicit list of queries over tables and columns.

Comment: I see the problem, but I just want to search a table. Sorry, should have specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select co11, ...
from tab1
where col1 like '%'||chr(9)||'%'  -- ascii code for tab
   or col1 like '%'||chr(20)||'%' -- ascii code for newline
--...
;
```